# Watchman connection refused, prevents react-native run-android

Tags: android-studio, react-native, watchman

When I run `react-native run-android` on my project I get the following error:

```
Loading dependency graph...
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ../../index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1)2019-01-27T11:26:16,173: 
[cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/var/run/watchman/myusername-state/sock! (Connection refused)
```

Somewhat related, I get the same error when I run step 3i) in the following link to help my android emulator get up and running. 
https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/solved-unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-bdc5e3a3d5ff

Please let me know if you know anything I can do to help. I tried

```
brew uninstall watchman
brew install --HEAD watchman
```

But I get an error when I have the HEAD Flag

```
Library/Logs/Homebrew/watchman/01.autogen.sh:
  File "./getdeps.py", line 629, in <module>
    main()
  File "./getdeps.py", line 608, in main
    install_platform_deps()
  File "./getdeps.py", line 537, in install_platform_deps
    allow_fail=True,
  File "./getdeps.py", line 283, in run_cmd
    subprocess.call(cmd, env=env, cwd=cwd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But when I just do `brew install watchman` it installs fine but I still cant load the dependency graph